# Should frontend or backend utilise web services?

Tags: php, rest, angularjs

We're developing a system in PHP and we want to utilize web services. Should the web pages through a framework like angular communicate to the web service to fetch the data, or should the back-end communicate to the web service and generate the results that is sent to the browser.

You can see from sites like Facebook that the data is actually provided as part of the page returned in JSON or some other format. It will then be processed by their JavaScript to render the page element.

Comment: Yes, it's a pretty valid behavior.

Comment: you mean it's more common the consume the webservice from the backend?

Comment: no. if you can trust third-party REST API - use it from front-end, no reasons for extra proxy layer on backend.

Comment: actually we were thinking of developing our own web service that we would consume. wouldn't handling it all from the frontend will make the user wait a bit longer. for example, if there's a lot of resources to be fetched to render a page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS and other frameworks like EmberJS usually create what it's known as **Single Page Application's (SPA)**. The goal is to separate your client (front end) completely from your backend.

In what I like to call the old days (although this is quite a common practice still), you had a server that renders your HTML through a template engine (php has Smarty, RoR has slim and erb, and there are many multi language implementations like Mustache and Handlebars). The problem with this approach is that you have your client logic completely attached to your backend logic, so when your product grows, your developers need to maintain logic in both ends (front end and back end).

This wasn't a problem years ago because views were quite simple: html forms, selects, divs, images. However, in the last 4-5 years Javascript and CSS has received quite a bump: you can do amazing things with just a few lines of code. Having a developer that it's able to maintain such rich applications (term aka as RIA's thanks to the Flex + Adobe family) AND a backed is a rare gem and quite expensive to hire (they are known as *Full Stack Developers*). Most of the time, they are never good in all of the web stack because the amount of knowledge required. Let's not mention the interaction you need to have with designers, users and managers.

Nowadays it's more common to have a team of front end people that are the glue with the designers, and code in Javascript that connects then with a REST backend. This backed is usually maintained by Back end developers and returns responses in XML or JSON format. Since the data is the only thing we care about (as the Front End is handled by apps like AngularJS), Back end people don't have to deal with CSS or JS, which by now is a monster as hard to tame as any backend language.

Answer (score 0):

In my websites which used webservice. I alway use front-end for communicate to the web service to fetch the data.

Backend will be used  as a supervisor of the communication.